# BOOTMGR is compressed

Tags: windows-7, compression

So I've just finished messing up my computer beyond repair. I originally had a Windows 7 install on my 64GB SSD and all my data on my 1.5TB HDD. So I decided to install Windows 8 Consumer Preview. I tried to clone my 64GB SSD onto my HDD; but that didn't work either at first. I later learned that it wiped all my data off of it. Thank goodness for the cloud. So I retried the cloning after I realized that my data was gone, and I finished it. So I rebooted and got a cryptic error message: BOOTMGR is compressed. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart.

So I did. Several times. I followed the instructions to rebuild the bootmanager from many websites, including HowToGeek, smallvoid.com, and more. None worked.

BTW, I've lost my Windows 7 Professional DVDs. All I have is my Windows 7 Home Premium DVD. It's the one I got with my laptop.

How can I get back to a working computer? I'm willing to wipe anything, as my data is all in the cloud.

Comment: *> So I've just finished messing up my computer beyond repair.*   Congratulations and welcome to the club. Gooble-gobble, gooble-gobble. You can pick up your membership kit (which contains a logo’d hat, t-shirt, keychain, and frisbee) at the club headquarters.          *> I later learned that it wiped all my data off of it*   Ouch! That’s why I don’t trust any software (not even that which I write myself) and always try to do everything—especially potentially destructive actions like partitioning—myself instead of letting installation software do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all: It's a DVD, not a CD. ;)

Second: Your story sounds a bit cloudy. :(

Third:

- Boot from the DVD.
- Click "Repair your Computer"
- Select "Restore your computer", and click Next
- Click "Cancel" on the two screens that pop up
- Click "Command Prompt"
- In the command prompt:

  - **EDIT**: Simply `compact /U C:\bootmgr` should work. If so, skip the next steps & just reboot!
  - Since `BootMgr` is hidden, type in `Attrib -S -H +R C:\BootMgr` and press Enter
  - Assuming there is no error, type in `Notepad` and press Enter
  - Browse to C:\
  - Select `Files of type: Show all files`
  - You should see `BootMgr` in the list. Right-click it, and go to Properties, then Advanced.
  - Unselect "Compress contents to save disk space", and press OK/OK
  - Back in the command prompt, type in `Attrib +S +H +R C:\BootMgr`
- Reboot

This will decompress the boot manager, which will hopefully be enough. But if it isn't, you can use the same process to decompress other files/folders.

Comment: The sheer badassery of this answer deserves **so many** upvotes.

Comment: @NReilingh: I'm assuming you got stuck in a similar position. And yes, this answer *is* pretty badass, seeing as it saved me from several formats, terabytes of data download from the cloud, and two OS reinstalls.

Comment: @NReilingh: Haha thanks. xD @JavaAndCSharp: Glad it helped! I just remembered there's an even easier way to do this... a simple `compact /U C:\bootmgr` would've also solved the problem. :-) I'll update that.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding boot manager won't work, since even if you do rebuild it, the compression attributes remain & the bootmanager will get recompressed.

This is what I did when I was in a similar situation:

- Boot from the Windows 7 DVD (any edition will work).
- Click 'Repair my Computer'
- At the prompt to select your OS installation, click the button that says 'Load Drivers'. This should bring up a explorer-style drive browser.
- Right-click on the drive you tried to compress(most probably the C drive), and deselect 'Compress this Drive', which should still be ticked on. Hit apply, and apply to subfolders/files.

Comment: Hmm. This sounds like it'll work; I'll try it tomorrow morning.

Comment: I tried Mehrdad's answer above and it worked.

Comment: glad to hear, @JavaAndCSharp

Comment: @Sathya - You mind getting rid of this answer considering Mehrdad's answer worked.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't see why I need to remove it. It's an alternative, posted before him & will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Windows 7 Professional ISO from Microsoft.
2. Make a bootable DVD of Windows 7 And Windows 8.
3. First install Windows 8.
4. Partition your HDD to minimum 20GB.
5. Install Windows 7 from the DVD.
6. Use the SSD to store files.

Comment: erm... This question was already answered with an answer that was way simpler and easier. What's the point of this one?